# Non-Stack's Imgur images may disappear soon, help us migrate them to Stack's Imgur account

Tags: support, image, hyperlinks

As announced on [Imgur TOS change on May 15th could cause the loss of thousands of Stack Exchange images!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/241919),

> On May 15th, Imgur will implement its [new TOS](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/14415587638029-Imgur-Terms-of-Service-Update-April-19-2023-), in which
>
> > We will be focused on removing old, unused, and inactive content that is not tied to a user account.

At the time of writing, there are:

- [`url:i.imgur.com`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.imgur.com): 216 posts
- [`url:https://imgur`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fimgur): 71 posts
- [`i.imgur.com`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=i.imgur.com): 21 posts
- [`imgur.com`](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=imgur.com): 31 posts

containing non-Stack's Imgur images.

These images need to be migrated to Stack's Imgur account. We need your help by reuploading the images and replacing the links (quick way: copy the original image, then paste it inside the editor). Let's get started!

Comment: Can't this be automated?

Comment: @804b18f832fb419fb142 [perhaps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388726/241919), we'll see later when they have the resources to execute it network-wide.

Answer (score 0):

These posts have some issues when migrating the images:

- [insert post link] - *reason here*